# Give an example where this fails if G is not abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If G is an abelian group and n$\in \mathbb{Z}$, show that $H_n=\{g\in G:g=x^n\ $ for some $x\in G \}$  is a subgroup of G . Give an example where this fails if G is not abelian.

I know the fist part to show $H_n$ is a subgroup. But I failed to find the example. I have tried Klein Four group , Dihedral group. Still can't find such a non abelian group. Why can non abelian group be so rare.

Comment: The smallest possible example is an example.

Comment: @Randall  Do you mean Klein Four group?

Comment: @LOIS The Klein Four group is abelian; you want the smallest non-abelian group. Do you know what it is?

Comment: What @ArnaudD. said.

Comment: @Arnaud D.  I see. I made a mistake . Klein Four group is abelian and so does the group with order less than 6.  The smallest non abelian group should be Dihedral group with order 6. But it seems $H_2$ is a subgroup of $D_6$ , $H_3$ is itself.  I denote $D_6$ like this $D_6=<r,s>$ where $ord (r)=3,ord(s)=2$, then $D_6=\{e,r,r^2,s,rs,r^2s\}$ , the 2-nd power of its elements are {e,r^2,r,e,e,e} , hence $H_2={e,r,r^2}$ which can form a group.  What's wrong in this?

Comment: @LOIS  I removed my answer as you correctly pointed out my mistake. If I can salvage it I will.

Comment: OK, it has been salvaged.  It was significantly different from my first (really wrong) answer that I started a new answer, deleting the old and giving up the rep points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second comment was right.  $H_2$ does in fact form a subgroup in $D_6$.  This is a fluke, and it need not happen.

In $D_6$ it is $H_3$ that goes wrong.  If you work out all cubes (not hard once you've already worked out the squares, since $a^3=(a^2)a$), you get
$$
H_3 =\{ e, s, rs, r^2s\}.
$$
To do this you need the defining relation $srs=r^{-1}$ (and its cousin $sr=r^{-1}s$ is useful for computing the cube of $r^2s$).
But this is not a subgroup as it is not closed under the inherited operation:
$$
s \cdot rs = srs = r^{-1}=r^2 \notin H_3.
$$
Or, if you already have Lagrange at your disposal, it cannot be a subgroup as it has order $4$ inside a group of order $6$.